# Difference between JE/JNE and JZ/JNZ

Tags: assembly, x86

In x86 assembly code, are `JE` and `JNE` exactly the same as `JZ` and `JNZ`?

Comment: Long answer: yes.

Comment: Short answer: no. (But they correspond to *exactly* the same machine code, so they do *exactly* the same thing. They just have different mnemonics for the same comparison.)

Comment: JE means jump if equal, it is equal if a prior compare has the z flag set, JZ means jump if the z flag is set.  They are exactly the same, some folks want to think/write in terms of my compare was equal or not equal.  Some folks think and write in terms of is the z flag set or z flag clear.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`JE` and `JZ` are just different names for exactly the same thing: a
conditional jump when `ZF` (the "zero" flag) is equal to 1.

(Similarly, `JNE` and `JNZ` are just different names for a conditional jump
when `ZF` is equal to 0.)

You *could* use them interchangeably, but you *should* use them depending on
what you are doing:

- `JZ`/`JNZ` are more appropriate when you are explicitly testing
  for something being equal to zero:

  ```
  dec  ecx
  jz   counter_is_now_zero
  ```
- `JE` and `JNE` are more appropriate after a `CMP` instruction:

  ```
  cmp  edx, 42
  je   the_answer_is_42
  ```

  (A `CMP` instruction performs a subtraction, and throws the value of the result away, while keeping the flags; which is why you get `ZF=1` when the operands are equal
  and `ZF=0` when they're not.)

Comment: TL:DR: same machine operation, different *semantic* meaning.  Just like `jb` / `jc` / `jnae` all testing CF=1.  See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc (or cmovcc or setcc)

Answer (score 51):

From the [Intel's manual - Instruction Set Reference](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/789581/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-s-manual-combined-volumes-2a-2b-2c-and-2d-instruction-set-reference-a-z.html), the `JE` and `JZ` have the same opcode (`74` for rel8 / `0F 84` for rel 16/32) also  `JNE` and `JNZ` (`75` for rel8 / `0F 85` for rel 16/32) share opcodes.

`JE` and `JZ` they both check for the `ZF` (or zero flag), although the manual differs slightly in the descriptions of the first `JE` rel8 and `JZ` rel8 `ZF` usage, but basically they are the same.

Here is an extract from the manual's pages 658-660:

```
 Op Code    | mnemonic  | Description
 -----------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------  
 74 cb      | JE rel8   | Jump short if equal (ZF=1).
 74 cb      | JZ rel8   | Jump short if zero (ZF ← 1).

 0F 84 cw   | JE rel16  | Jump near if equal (ZF=1). Not supported in 64-bit mode.
 0F 84 cw   | JZ rel16  | Jump near if 0 (ZF=1). Not supported in 64-bit mode.

 0F 84 cd   | JE rel32  | Jump near if equal (ZF=1).
 0F 84 cd   | JZ rel32  | Jump near if 0 (ZF=1).

 75 cb      | JNE rel8  | Jump short if not equal (ZF=0).
 75 cb      | JNZ rel8  | Jump short if not zero (ZF=0).

 0F 85 cd   | JNE rel32 | Jump near if not equal (ZF=0).
 0F 85 cd   | JNZ rel32 | Jump near if not zero (ZF=0).
```

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc is an HTML extract of the Intel's PDF.  Since I've already read the intro chapters of the PDF and know what the notation is trying to convey, just the per-instruction manual entries are most useful and quick to open.