# NASM changes JNZ to JNE while assembling? Why?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, disassembly

I have a piece of code which uses JNZ. When I assemble and link the binary, I see my JNZ is replaces with a JNE. I  understand that both of them fundamentally are the same. But then why does NASM change it?

Also, is there any config option available to stop this change from happening while assembling?

Comment: Take some time to read CPU documentation. JE and JZ are the same thing. And so are JNE and JNZ.

Comment: why do we need them both?

Comment: Why do we have synonyms, aliases, nicknames and such? They serve some purpose. What is more natural to think of, `Equality` or `Zero` after `ADD AX, 1`? Now, answer the same question for `CMP AX, 1`.

Comment: Thanks! You almost sound angry when answering though :)

Comment: I'm simply amazed to see lack of effort where you could have easily found the answer yourself.

Comment: You come on. :) You'll be a better programmer if you are proactive.

Comment: because [they're the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267081/difference-between-je-jne-and-jz-jnz)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I understand that both of them fundamentally are the same

`JNE` and `JNZ` have the [same opcodes](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) (`0x75` for short jumps and `0x0f 0x85` for near jumps), so the assembler will create the **same machine code** for both of them.

When disassembling, the disassembler does not known anymore which one was used in the source and it has to take one of them.

> Also, is there any config option available to stop this change from happening while assembling?

No, because it is not a real "replacement" - `JNE` and `JNZ` are simply different mnemonics for the same opcodes.

Comment: My next question is then why need them both?

Comment: You can use them to make your code more readable and easier to understand - use `JNE` followed by a `CMP` instruction to make clear that you are checking for **equality**, and use `JNZ` if you simply want to check the zero flag (e.g. after a `SUB` instruction to check if the result is zero or not)

Answer (score 2):

`JNZ` and `JNE` have exactly the same encoding (refer to Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Vol. 2A 3-419). So whichever you use in the assembler, the disassembler would pick one and use the same notation throughout in the disassembled code.