# conditional jumps in assembly

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements

i've got question about conditional jumps in assembly. i've got basic knowledgle of them, but i ran into a situation where conditional jump jne is used after an dec instruction, something like that:

1. dec rdx
2. jne for

And i'm curious is this gonna work? because technically jne jump execution is based on value of ZF, so untill decrementation of rdx doesnt make it's value 0, the ZF will be 0, so this jump should be executed. But maybe jnz jump should be used instead to make it more right and simple? And jne jump should be used after cmp intructions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267081/difference-between-je-jne-and-jz-jnz

Comment: Is that what you're asking?  If not, I can re-open.